# Find the address a Module is loadet into (memory)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory, cheat-engine

I used CE to get a pointer to a value.
I want to implement the pointer into my C++ Visual Studio Code.
It has 3 Offsets.

What I already got:

- Get the Process ID
- Add the Offsets to the base address

What I need:

- The """base address"""

Problem: I'm not sure if that what I am really looking for is the "base address".

[POINTER I GOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzwRM.png)

**What I need is** the Value that = 0x141B6658 - 0x5C4C0 = **0x1415A198   = ???**

How to get that **0x1415A198** automatically?

I first thought this is the base address of the Module "N3.dll", which would make sense..(?), but it doesn't seem like it is.

I'm grabbing the Module base address with  modueentry32, handle=CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, PID), me32.modBaseAddr

And that is something like

```
MODULE NAME:     N3.dll
     executable     = D:\xxx\xxx\xxx\N3.dll
     process ID     = 0x00003C2C
     ref count (g)  =     0x0004
     ref count (p)  =     0x0004
     base address   = 0x53230000
     base size      = 401408
```

But that's not even close to the one I need

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that is not simply repeating the tag information. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to be of use to a future reader here who is scanning a list of search results. Repeating tags does not help that user. The title should describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to expect that `base address   = 0x53230000` holds everything related to N3.dll. This isn't true; that's the base address where code and constants for N3.dll have been loaded. But anything allocated by `new` will be allocated memory at runtime. There are no module offsets involved in that.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that information! Is there a way to grab that address the N3.dll is loadet into at runtime?

Comment: @xKean: That *is* the base address.

Comment: Hm. Okay thank you! Im gonna try around a little, maybe i can figure out how it works.. Have to get from base adress -> dynamic adress i can change the value in. Gonna report soon.